# Knockout best practices. If or visible

Tags: javascript, optimization, knockout.js

I'm looking for knockout *if* or *visible* best practices in this case:

```
<div data-bind="visible: $root.obsVar()">
    ...
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: $root.obsVar().someField" />
    ...
</div>
```

In case when `$root.obsVar()` is undefined, error will be thrown. If you change `visible` to `if`, problem will miss, but it requires rewriting of the html. If there is a lot of murkup in `div`, it takes a lot of time. Are there any reasons to change `$root.obsVar().someField` to `$root.getSomeFieldValue` that always returns correct value or undefined? Or maybe there are other techniques not to get overhead and avoid errors.

Comment: In this scenario, `if` or `with` would be the more correct thing to do. It *should* also be easy to do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It really depends on the scenario. From the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html):

> `if` plays a similar role to the `visible` binding. The difference is that, with `visible`, the contained markup always remains in the DOM and always has its `data-bind` attributes applied - the `visible` binding just uses CSS to toggle the container element’s visiblity. The `if` binding, however, physically adds or removes the contained markup in your DOM, and only applies bindings to descendants if the expression is true.

In your scenario, the only way to prevent an error without using `if`, when `someField` is null, is to do something along these lines:

```
data-bind="value: ($root.obsVar() == null) ? null : $root.obsVar().someField"
```

That's really annoying to have to write each time you access a property. It makes the code harder to maintain and it makes it easier to make a mistake—especially when you're adding a new binding to an `obsVar`'s property because you will have to remember to do that null check.

Unless you see some clear performance benefits from using `visible` in your situation, my recommendation would be to go with `if` because then you only have to write the check in one place and not multiple places.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I feared that miss some true-way to organize js code.

Answer (score 2):

You might find you need to use both.

Use `if` to remove the markup from the DOM - preventing possible JS errors, and so it doesn't take up space on the page.

And then use `visible` to hide the element until the page is fully loaded.

```
<!-- ko if: whatever -->
<div data-bind="visible: true" style="display: none">
    my content
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: this is right response, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using $root.obsVar without the (). That should work for either if or visible. The difference between the two is that "visible" just hides the div, which will still exist in the DOM, but "if" leaves it out of the DOM.

Comment: The problem not in `$root.obsVar()` but in `$root.obsVar().someField` because can not get `someField` of `undefined`. But if using `if` then that part of code does not exists and code does not run.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in David Sherret's answer, the main difference is that with `if` the DOM elements disappear if the condition is not fulfilled, and with `visible` they're simply hidden, but are always present in the DOM tree.

The main consequence is that if you're using `if` and you have to handle events you'll have to use delegated events, or attach them everytime the elements are recreated. When you use KO you usually don't do event handling, because you use bindings like `click` which are handled by KO, and so you don't have this problem. But you can have some other frameworks involved, like validators, jQuery UI date pickers, and so on, which will have trouble to work correctly with KO's `if`.